# Getting last four (04) figures

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Below is my code with the files and output file.  The last four calculations are giving me the most trouble, mainly the DISCNT PRCNT.

I'm not getting the correct output in discnt percnt; trying to figure out how to display it in the column; and if the purchase qty is above qty discnt level then that rate times gross = discount amount.

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
  ******************************************************************
  * DEFINES THE EXTERNAL FILES - INPUT & OUTPUT FILES              *
  ******************************************************************
   CONFIGURATION   SECTION.

   INPUT-OUTPUT    SECTION.

   FILE-CONTROL.
  *
       SELECT TRANSACTION-FILE
          ASSIGN "TRANSACTION.TXT" ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
  *
       SELECT PR-MASTER-FILE
          ASSIGN "MSTRSRT.TXT" ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
          ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM
          RECORD KEY IS PR-PROD-NUM
          FILE STATUS IS SW-FILE-STATUS.
  *
       SELECT PRINT-FILE
          ASSIGN "ORDER_REPORT.TXT" ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
  *
  *
   DATA DIVISION.
  *
   FILE SECTION.
  *
  *
   FD  PR-MASTER-FILE.
  *
   01  PR-MASTER-RECORD.
       05  PR-PROD-NUM              PIC XXX.
       05  PR-PROD-DESC             PIC X(27).
       05  PR-UNIT-PRICE            PIC 9(03)V99.
       05  PR-MIN-ORDER             PIC 9(03).
       05  PR-QTY-DISCNT-LEVEL      PIC 9(03).
       05  PR-DISCNT-PRCNT          PIC 9V99.
       05  PR-GRAND-TOTAL           PIC S9(05)V99.
  *
   FD TRANSACTION-FILE.
   01  TR-TRANSACTION-RECORD.
       05  TR-CUST-NAME             PIC X(25).
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(05).
       05  TR-PROD-QTY              PIC 9(03).
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  TR-PROD-NUM              PIC 9(03).
  *
  *
   FD  PRINT-FILE.
  *
   01  LINEOUT                      PIC X(160).
  *
  *
  /
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *
  *
   01 PRICES.
  *  05  W-UNIT-PRICE-EDITED          PIC ZZZV99.
     05  W-GROSS-PRICE                PIC S9(05)V99.
     05  W-QTY-DISCNT-AMNT            PIC S9(07)V99.
     05  W-SALES-TAX                  PIC S9(06)V99.
     05  W-NET-PRICE                  PIC S9(09)V99.
     05  W-NET-PRICE-EDITED           PIC ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZV99.
  *
  *
   01  SWITCHES.
       05  SW-FILE-STATUS           PIC XX.
       05  PR-EOF                   PIC X VALUE "N".
  *
   01  HL-HEADING-LINE.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(35) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(16) VALUE "ORDER REPORT".

   01  HL-HEADING-COLUMNS-01.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(60) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(06) VALUE "UNIT".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(09) VALUE "GROSS".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(06) VALUE "SALES ".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(08) VALUE "DISCNT".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(11) VALUE "DISCNT".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(08) VALUE "NET".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(10) VALUE "GRAND".
  *
   01  HL-HEADING-COLUMNS-02.

       05  FILLER                   PIC X(25) VALUE "CUSTOMER".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(27) VALUE "PRODUCT".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(03) VALUE "QTY".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(06) VALUE "PRICE".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(02) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(06) VALUE "PRICE".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(05) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(06) VALUE "TAX".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(08) VALUE "PERCNT".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(09) VALUE "AMOUNT".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(10) VALUE "PRICE".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(07) VALUE "TOTAL".
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01) VALUE SPACES.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(15) VALUE "MESSAGE".
  *
   01  DL-DETAIL-LINE.
       05  DL-CUST-NAME             PIC X(25).
  *     05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-PROD-NUM              PIC X(03).
  *     05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-PROD-DESC             PIC X(26).
  *     05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-PROD-QTY              PIC ZZZ.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-UNIT-PRICE            PIC ZZZ.99.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-GROSS-PRICE           PIC ZZ,ZZ9.99.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-SALES-TAX             PIC Z,ZZ9.99.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(04).
       05  DL-DISCNT-PRCNT          PIC Z.99.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-QTY-DISCNT-AMNT       PIC ZZ,ZZ9.99.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-NET-PRICE             PIC X(11).
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-GRAND-TOTAL           PIC ZZ,ZZ9.99.
       05  FILLER                   PIC X(01).
       05  DL-MESSAGE               PIC X(15).
  *
  *
  /
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   000-MAINLINE.

        OPEN INPUT  TRANSACTION-FILE
             I-O  PR-MASTER-FILE
             OUTPUT PRINT-FILE

        WRITE LINEOUT FROM HL-HEADING-LINE AFTER PAGE
        WRITE LINEOUT FROM HL-HEADING-COLUMNS-01 AFTER 2
        WRITE LINEOUT FROM HL-HEADING-COLUMNS-02 AFTER 1
        PERFORM UNTIL PR-EOF = "Y"

            READ TRANSACTION-FILE
               AT END
                  MOVE "Y" TO PR-EOF
               NOT AT END
                  PERFORM 100-PROCESS-TRANSACTION
            END-READ

        END-PERFORM

        CLOSE TRANSACTION-FILE PR-MASTER-FILE PRINT-FILE.
        STOP RUN.

  *
  *
   100-PROCESS-TRANSACTION.

        MOVE SPACES TO DL-DETAIL-LINE

        MOVE TR-CUST-NAME TO DL-CUST-NAME

        MOVE TR-PROD-NUM TO DL-PROD-NUM
        MOVE TR-PROD-NUM TO PR-PROD-NUM

        READ PR-MASTER-FILE
           INVALID KEY
              MOVE ALL"*" TO DL-UNIT-PRICE
              MOVE ALL"*" TO DL-NET-PRICE
              MOVE "NO FILE" TO DL-MESSAGE
          NOT INVALID KEY

              PERFORM 110-PROCESS-TRANSACTION

        END-READ

        WRITE LINEOUT FROM DL-DETAIL-LINE AFTER 2.
  *
  *
   110-PROCESS-TRANSACTION.

        MOVE PR-PROD-DESC TO DL-PROD-DESC
        MOVE PR-UNIT-PRICE  TO DL-UNIT-PRICE
        MOVE TR-PROD-QTY TO DL-PROD-QTY


        IF TR-PROD-QTY < PR-MIN-ORDER
           MOVE ALL"*" TO DL-NET-PRICE
           MOVE "BELOW MIN" TO DL-MESSAGE

        ELSE

         MULTIPLY TR-PROD-QTY BY PR-UNIT-PRICE GIVING W-GROSS-PRICE
           MOVE W-GROSS-PRICE TO DL-GROSS-PRICE

         MULTIPLY W-GROSS-PRICE BY 0.07 GIVING W-SALES-TAX
           MOVE W-SALES-TAX TO DL-SALES-TAX


           IF TR-PROD-QTY > PR-QTY-DISCNT-LEVEL

        MULTIPLY PR-DISCNT-PRCNT BY 100 GIVING DL-DISCNT-PRCNT

          MOVE PR-DISCNT-PRCNT TO DL-DISCNT-PRCNT



  *            MULTIPLY W-GROSS-PRICE BY PR-DISCNT-PRCNT
  *            GIVING W-QTY-DISCNT-AMNT

  *            MOVE W-QTY-DISCNT-AMNT TO DL-QTY-DISCNT-AMNT
  *            SUBTRACT W-QTY-DISCNT-AMNT FROM W-GROSS-PRICE
           END-IF



          SUBTRACT W-SALES-TAX FROM W-GROSS-PRICE GIVING W-NET-PRICE
           MOVE W-NET-PRICE TO W-NET-PRICE-EDITED
           MOVE W-NET-PRICE-EDITED TO DL-NET-PRICE

           ADD W-NET-PRICE TO PR-GRAND-TOTAL
           REWRITE PR-MASTER-RECORD
           MOVE PR-GRAND-TOTAL TO DL-GRAND-TOTAL

        END-IF.
```

TR File:

```
LONELY LEO                    012 010
CHARLIE CHEAP                 001 743
WIDOW LADY                    123 565
MISSIONARY MIKE               999 085
UNKNOWN COMIC                 003 115
MUDFENCE MARTHA               200 115
SAM SENILE                    007 175
ERIK ESTRADSKI                001 204
SPACE CADET                   002 950
DATING BUREAU                 004 565
DORM COUNCIL                  450 900
LONESOME SAL                  001 010
BROADMOOR COUNCIL             020 900
DIRTY OLD LADY                010 899
LAST CUSTOMER                 999 999
```

PR File:

```
004EROTIC TOOTHBRUSH                    01098    001100     125
085HYMNAL                               01245    005010     085
010INFLATABLE ENEMY                     14095    005010     050
899SEARS GIFT CERT.                     10000    006010     100
115BROWN PAPER BAGS                     00005    100150     025
1752500VITAMIN E TABLETS                10000    002012     010
743BUDGET MOTEL GUIDE                   00606    006100     125
280RESERVED PARKING STICKER             99999    001100     300
565BLACK BOOK--FILLED IN                00100    003006     100
010BEST FRIEND                          14093    010015     050
280STUDENT PARKING STICKER              00010    001100     255
800SATIN SHEET SET                      05595    001012     100
400FRENCH POSTCARD                      00075    025050     050
900PLASTIC WHISTLES                     00104    012100     155
```

This is what I'm getting so far:

```
ORDER REPORT

                                                            UNIT   GROSS     SALES  DISCNT   DISCNT      NET      GRAND
CUSTOMER                  PRODUCT                     QTY  PRICE   PRICE      TAX    PERCNT   AMOUNT    PRICE      TOTAL   MESSAGE

LONELY LEO               010INFLATABLE ENEMY           12 140.95  1,691.40   118.39                         1,573 88,790.54

CHARLIE CHEAP            743BUDGET MOTEL GUIDE          1   6.06                                      ***********           BELOW MIN

WIDOW LADY               565BLACK BOOK--FILLED IN     123   1.00    123.00     8.61                           114 18,493.67

MISSIONARY MIKE          085HYMNAL                    999  12.45 12,437.55   870.62    5.00                11,566 15,750.72

UNKNOWN COMIC            115BROWN PAPER BAGS            3    .05                                      ***********           BELOW MIN

MUDFENCE MARTHA          115BROWN PAPER BAGS          200    .05     10.00     0.70     .00                     9  7,918.18

SAM SENILE               1752500VITAMIN E TABLETS       7 100.00    700.00    49.00                           651 40,683.42

ERIK ESTRADSKI           204                                 .00                                      ***********           NO FILE

SPACE CADET              950                                 .00                                      ***********           NO FILE

DATING BUREAU            565BLACK BOOK--FILLED IN       4   1.00      4.00     0.28                             3 18,497.39

DORM COUNCIL             900PLASTIC WHISTLES          450   1.04    468.00    32.76     .00                   435 28,341.14

LONESOME SAL             010INFLATABLE ENEMY            1 140.95                                      ***********           BELOW MIN

BROADMOOR COUNCIL        900PLASTIC WHISTLES           20   1.04     20.80     1.45     .00                    19 28,360.49

DIRTY OLD LADY           899SEARS GIFT CERT.           10 100.00  1,000.00    70.00     .00                   930 56,832.36

LAST CUSTOMER            999                                 .00                                      ***********           NO FILE
```

Comment: TLDR, could you please try to create a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/), to show us your very specific problem!

Comment: Need some specifics of the problem. What is going wrong. What exactly are the instructions involved (last four is clear to you, not to us). What is your expected result?

Comment: My Bad...Not getting the correct output in discnt percnt,  trying to figure out how to display it in the column, and if the purchase qty is above qty discnt level then that rate times gross = discount amount, but seems no matter which way I'm thinking which could be off a few since for last 8 hours i've been going nuts...

Comment: Your PR data shown doesn't match the PR-MASTER-RECORD. NUM and DESC look fine, but then you show 10 blanks before what is likely price (00104 for whistles) then four blanks before MIN-ORDER and DISCNT-LEVEL, five blanks before DISCNT-PRCNT and no sign of GRAND-TOTAL at all. You have other problems, but you need to confirm the data you are using matches your layouts. If it does, edit the correct data into your question. If not, probably best to start a new question with what is left.

Comment: If you find yourself getting nowhere with something, take a break, do something else. When you come back to it, clear out all your preconceptions of the program and the problem before starting again. Really, one of the first things to do as a beginner is to ensure that your data on files matches your record-layouts.

Comment: Another useful technique is to fully and accurately describe your problem to someone. While concentrating on doing that you will often spot something obvious. I call this the Cardboard Cut-Out Programmer. The CCOP doesn't need to be a programmer, and doesn't need to say anything beyond "I don't understand that bit (not in terms of programming, but in terms of understanding how parts logically fit from your explanation). Also known as Rubber Ducking, apparently.

Comment: The production of an SSCE, like @AndreasNiedermair mentioned, can help you present a minimal amount of code which exhibits the problem you are getting. In producing this, you will often discover what the problem is. Again as a beginner this can be useful to you (and to us). As you get more experienced, you should be able to do most/all of the code-reduction in your head. All of these things now are to train in how to think about programming problems. It may seem like extra work, but if you go through it, it'll say you 20 years of asking simple questions.

Comment: Thanks alot all the input....